# How to use Python object in an if statement

Tags: python, object

I have a Python program which uses one of two objects:

```
framework.interfaces.client.client_one.ClientOne
framework.interfaces.client.client_one.ClientTwo
```

Only one will be instantiated at any time and it will be held in a variable called `notification`.

I want to check which client is in use and do one thing if it's `ClientOne` and something different if it's `ClinetTwo`.

If I add `print(notification)` to my program I can see something like `<framework.interfaces.client.client_one.ClientOne object at 0x7f2e9ee09150>`. However I'm unable to do something like:

```py
if 'ClientOne' in notification:
    print('ClientOne')
elif 'ClientTwo' in notification:
    print('ClientTwo')
```

How can I check which object I'm using?

Comment: if there will only be one at a time, and you only have two, you could just do a try-except

Comment: What does `notification_services` contain?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It should be `notification`.

Comment: Is `notification` a container?

Comment: `it will be **held in** a variable` - https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: `if type(notification) == ClientOne:`

Answer (score 1):

Can you use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#isinstance)?

```py
from framework.interfaces.client.client_one import ClientOne, ClientTwo
from some_other_module import notification

if isinstance(notification, ClientOne):
    print('ClientOne')
elif isinstance(notification, ClientTwo):
    print('ClientTwo')
```

Comment: @wwii I am assuming @runnerpaul means to say that the instance of `ClientOne` or `ClientTwo` will be bound to `notification`. See their output from `print(notification)` above.